# GCC error undefined reference to function but function is defined, implemented, compiled

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile an executable with GCC but I'm getting an undefined reference to  error even though the function in question is defined in another header file, compiled in another source file and compiled to a .o file.

The error is raised by a call to a defined function in an intermediary .o file (file graph.o).

Here's the code:

makefile:

```
kosaraju: kosaraju.o string_linked_list.o graph.o [...]
    gcc -o ../kosaraju kosaraju.o string_linked_list.o graph.o [...] -Wall
    make clean
    
kosaraju.o: 
    gcc -o kosaraju.o kosaraju.c -c -Wall
    
graph.o:
    gcc -o graph.o graph.c -c -Wall
    
string_linked_list.o:
    gcc -o string_linked_list.o string_linked_list.c -c -Wall

...
```

graph.c

```
#include "string_linked_list.h"
#include "graph.h"
#include ...

...


void dfs1_step(char * node, string_linked_list * topological_sort, /*more stuff*/)
{

    {
     // DFS_step implementation
    }

    // after iteration marks as visited
    string_linked_list_push(topological_sort, node);
}
```

string_linked_list.h

```
#ifndef STRING_LINKED_LIST
#define STRING_LINKED_LIST
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct string_linked_list_node
{
    char * value;
    struct string_linked_list_node * next;
} string_linked_list_node;

typedef struct string_linked_list
{
    struct string_linked_list_node * head;
    struct string_linked_list_node * tail;
    uint16_t count;
} string_linked_list;

bool string_linked_list_push(string_linked_list * list, char * value);
// more prototypes
#endif
```

string_linked_list.c

```
#include "graph.h"
#include "string_linked_list.h"
#include //more stuff


// Problematic function
bool string_linked_list_push(string_linked_list * list, char * value)
{
    string_linked_list_node * new_node = malloc(sizeof(string_linked_list_node));
    new_node->value = calloc(1, NODE_ID_LEN);
    if (new_node == NULL || new_node->value == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    strncpy(new_node->value, value, NODE_ID_LEN);
    new_node->next = list->head->next;
    list->head->next = new_node;
    return true;
}

// more functions
```

the error I get after executing `make`:

```
gcc -o ../kosaraju kosaraju.c scanner.o map.o string_linked_list.o graph.o -Wall
/usr/bin/ld: graph.o: in function `dfs1_step':
graph.c:(.text+0x48a): undefined reference to `string_linked_list_push'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any insights on the reason? I've also tried to link `string_linked_list` directly into `graph.o` but had the same error.

I have implemented the `string_linked_list_push` in the correct file, I've checked if the signature matched it's definition in the header file, I've tried to link it directly into `graph.o` multiple times:

```
graph.o: string_linked_list.o
    gcc -o graph.o string_linked_list.o graph.c -Wall
```

and also:

```
graph.o:
    gcc -o graph.o string_linked_list.c graph.c -Wall
```

(I've actually tried with and without the `-c` option.

Comment: You are trying to compile `kosaraju.c` to executable binary: `gcc -o ../kosaraju kosaraju.c ...`. There should be `kosaraju.o`. Try `gcc -o ../kosaraju -Wall $^`  Generally, don't write compilation rules by yourself, use implicit rules!

Comment: @dimich that was a typo, the linking is being made to a `kosaraju.o` file

Comment: `make` doesn't know that it needs to re-compile `string_linked_list.o` whenever `string_linked_list.c` changes. So it doesn't re-compile it.

Comment: @user253751 actually forcing a rebuild solved the problem. a `make clean: rm -rf *.o *~` would have worked too. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make` doesn't know that it needs to re-compile `string_linked_list.o` whenever `string_linked_list.c` changes, because you didn't tell it that.

You asked it to link the program, so it does that, with the perfectly good .o files it already has, which don't have a `string_linked_list_push` function because you hadn't written that function last time you compiled that file.

And `make` doesn't see that you changed the file and added the next function, because you didn't tell it to do that. Solution: Tell it to do that.

Change:

```
string_linked_list.o:
```

to:

```
string_linked_list.o: string_linked_list.c
```

and do the same for the rest of the .o files.

There are shorter ways to write makefiles, but I'll leave you to explore them yourself when you get around to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about headers dependencies, your `Makefile` may be quite shorter:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall

kosaraju: kosaraju.o string_linked_list.o graph.o
```

Run `make -B` to force rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

```
kosaraju: kosaraju.o string_linked_list.o graph.o [...]
    gcc -o ../kosaraju kosaraju.o string_linked_list.o graph.o [...] -Wall
    make clean
```

here, you link `../kosaraju`, but your make target (the one that triggered the build) was `kosaraju`, (in the current working directory), which is most probably not what you want.  I don't know if this is the actual cause of your build failure, but can be, as this can be affecting your dependencies and linking old versions of your files.  Be careful with this.  Indeed, you will have noticed that the link phase is always executed, as you specify a command that actually doesn't build the target, but a different thing.  You should change that rule into this:

```
../kosaraju: kosaraju.o string_linked_list.o graph.o [...]
    gcc -o $@ kosaraju.o string_linked_list.o graph.o [...]
```

(don't use compiling options, like `-Wall` while linking, and never do a `make clean` as part of the build.  It is not common sense to destroy what you have just made)